# Is there any way to figure out if a system of two recurrence relations will converge?

Tags: linear-algebra, recurrence-relations, fractals, iterated-function-system

Context: I'm trying to write code that generates 2D Iterated Function System (IFS) fractals based on some affine transformations. I want to generate the fractal till convergence when possible.

The system of two recurrence relations I'm looking at are affine transformations of the form:

$x_{n+1} = ax_n + by_n + e$

$y_{n+1} = cx_n + dy_n + f$

where a, b, c, d, e, f are real numbers and $x_i, y_i$ are integers.

I'm trying to figure out the conditions for which $x_i$ and $y_i$ would eventually converge but I have not made much progress yet. The only thing I can think of is that it will only converge if a, b, c and d are within the range (-1, 1). But I'm not sure if this is enough to ensure convergence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the eigenvalues of the matrix $A=\begin {pmatrix} a&b\\c&d \end {pmatrix}$ to be less than $1$ in absolute value.  Unless there is something special about your problem, the matrix will have two eigenvalues, each with a corresponding eigenvector.  The requirement is the same as for a geometric series, which is the one dimensional equivalent of what you have here.  You can write your iteration in terms of $X=\begin {pmatrix} x\\y \end {pmatrix}$ and $E=\begin {pmatrix} e\\f \end {pmatrix}$ as $X_{n+1}=AX_n+E$ with the limit found by $X=AX+E, X=(1-A)^{-1}E$

Comment: This is sufficient, but it's not necessary.  For instance if $e = f = x_0 = y_0 = 0$ then the sequence is all zeroes regardless of what $A$ is.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury:  that is correct.  There can be a fixed point even if the eigenvalues are greater than $1$ in absolute value, but it will be an unstable fixed point.  Any perturbation will make the values run off to infinity.